# Is there a way to filter out the healthcheck logs of an ASP.NET Core 6 app in AzureAppService when using ApplicationInsights

Tags: c#, logging, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have setup an ASP.NET Core 6.0 web app that uses Azure ApplicationInsights.

Healthcheck is configured like this:

```
public class Startup 
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
            services.AddHealthChecks();
            ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            ...
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/healthz");
        });
    }
}
```

And when I deploy my app to azure app service my live-metrics are clogged with healthchecks:

[image]

I see in a [blogpost](https://andrewwburns.com/2022/06/06/filtering-app-insights-server-side-health-check-requests/) that someone has written custom filters inside the app.

Is it possible to configure this in a more easy way?

**EDIT**: The quickest way was to target the logging with this config. Less accurate than accepted solution but required only config changes.

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
    },
    //save healthcheck output in the storage account
    "AzureAppServicesBlob": {
        "IncludeScopes": true,
        "LogLevel": {        
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Information",
        }
    },
    //ignore it in the applicationinsights (live-metrics)
    "ApplicationInsights": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            // healthcheck namespace
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics": "Warning"
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Information level logs are IMHO more important than removing health checks.  Seeing call times and connectivity issues and the response code has saved the teams i have been involved in huge amounts of trouble shooting time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by using an `ITelemetryInitializer`

```
    public class FilterHealthchecksTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public FilterHealthchecksTelemetryInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
        }
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if ((_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Path.Value?.StartsWith("/healthz", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                // We don't want to track health checks in the metrics.
                if (telemetry is ISupportAdvancedSampling advancedSampling)
                    advancedSampling.ProactiveSamplingDecision = SamplingDecision.SampledOut;

                // For the case that we cannot filter out the telemetry, we mark it as synthetic
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(telemetry.Context.Operation.SyntheticSource))
                    telemetry.Context.Operation.SyntheticSource = "HealthCheck";
            }
        }
    }
```

Then just add an instance to your services and Application Insights will pick it up

```
services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, FilterHealthchecksTelemetryInitializer>();
```

Comment: I do like the freedom of your solution, but 1 issue I have is that I would like to block the healthcheck only from live-metrics, but still save them in storage account output. I"ve added an alternate solution in my answer.